# How to delay the execution of a task in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I have got the following function on my program that runs perfectly. I am only updating some text on 3 labels on my GUI as the code shows and that is working fine. However, I want to put a 1-second delay/pause after each label update so that I can have label1 updated then after 1 second label2 gets updated and after 1 second again label3 updates. I have tried to use Thread. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me.

Thank you.

private void displayData()
{

```
DataHelper datahelper = new DataHelper(data1, data2, data3);

myThread = new Service<DataHelper>()
{
    @Override
    protected Task<DataHelper> createTask()
    {
        return new Task<DataHelper>()
        {
            protected DataHelper call() throws Exception
            {
                return new DataHelper(myData1, myData2, myData3);
            }
        };
    }
};

myThread.setOnSucceeded(event ->
{
    label1.textProperty().unbind();
    labe2.textProperty().unbind();
    label3.textProperty().unbind();
});

label1.textProperty().bindBidirectional(datahelper.text1Property());
label2.textProperty().bindBidirectional(datahelper.text2Property());
label3.textProperty().bindBidirectional(datahelper.text3Property());

myThread.restart();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the binding with delay of 1 second in each execution, you can use Timeline.

```
Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), ae -> lbl1.textProperty().bindBidirectional(data.text1Property())),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), ae -> lbl2.textProperty().bindBidirectional(data.text2Property())),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), ae -> lbl3.textProperty().bindBidirectional(data.text3Property())));
tl.setCycleCount(1);
tl.play();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sai. This is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked :). If your issue is addressed please mark the question as answered.